# .cscfg file gives error when i specify <Setting name="serilog:write-to:AzureDocumentDB.endpointUrl" />

Tags: c#, azure, web-config, azure-cosmosdb, serilog

When I publish my API project to Azure here is the error what i'm getting.
[image]

Is there any way to resolve this issue and here is the code and the problem comes when this symbol "**:**" is init.

[image]

Here are some more details.

1. It's a web API Project
2. Version 4.6
3. Locally it's running without any issues but when it comes to release automation I should be able to change the value of endpointurl , key, and TTL manually so that I need to modify .csfg and .csdef file environment to environment. When i do that .csdef does not support that colon mark ":" so the build fails.

[image]

- Expecting : Build is successful so that the log works as expected.
- Actual : Build fails and log is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is not supported.

[ServiceDefinition:NamedElementNameString doesn't allow ':' (colon) in name](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/792)

So that I implemented custom configuration values and extract the values at run-time when the logger is initialized.

Here is the implementation.

.cscfg, .csdef, and web.config contains

```
<add key="LogEndpointUrl" value="xxxxxx/" />
<add key="LogAuthorizationKey" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=" />
<add key="LogTTL" value="1" />
```

When initializing got the values as follows from web.config

```
var endpoint = Common.Configuration.GetSetting(Constants.AppSettings.LogEndpointUrl);
var authorizationKey = Common.Configuration.GetSetting(Constants.AppSettings.LogAuthorizationKey);
int ttl = (int)Convert.ToInt64((Common.Configuration.GetSetting(Constants.AppSettings.LogTTL)));
```

And then

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.AppSettings().WriteTo.AzureDocumentDB(endpoint, authorizationKey,timeToLive: ttl).CreateLogger();

// Used to debug serilog itself and confirm it is writing entries to document db
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(Console.Out);
var errorOrInformation = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    errorOrInformation.Add(Constants.LoggingProperties.PartitionKey, logMetadata.PartitionKey);
    errorOrInformation.Add(Constants.LoggingProperties.RowKey, logMetadata.RowKey);
//Add as many items as you want

Log.Verbose("Log Information Message {Information}", errorOrInformation);
// Also good idea to force flush of log entries before the app ends
Log.CloseAndFlush();
```

Comment: @TomSun Yes above answer is correct and solved my issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that ServiceDefinition:NamedElementNameString doesn't allow ':' (colon) in name. But we could add it with Azure friendly name. Then we could get it with following code. I also do a demo on my side, it works as expected.

```
var endpoint = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("endpointUrl");
var authorizationKey = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("authorizationKey");
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
             .WriteTo.Console() //if no writeto.console there is no document in documentdb
             .WriteTo.AzureDocumentDB(endpoint, authorizationKey)
             .CreateLogger();
logger.Information("Tom Test");//log demo
```

About .csdef configuration please refer to the screenshot.
We could get more information from [Configure Azure cloud service roles with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-configure-roles-for-cloud-service)

[image]

Check from Azure Portal:

[image]

Related serilog sdk

[image]